# Why aren’t Tom, Jake, and Jen­ny look­ing for­ward to Thanks­giv­ing?

Tags: etymology, nouns, terminology, vocabulary, gender-positive

And “Hen” (their moth­er) isn’t much look­ing for­ward to it ei­ther.

Why? I can an­swer that ques­tion my­self: it’s be­cause they are
all [tur­keys](http://www2.ca.uky.edu/smallflocks/Poultry101-turkeys.html).

- *Tom* is an adult male tur­key (al­so of­ten re­ferred to as a ‘gob­bler’).
- *Hen* is an adult fe­male tur­key.
- *Jake* is a young male tur­key.
- *Jen­ny* is a young fe­male tur­key.

Very of­ten when we de­cide to name our pets we give them hu­man names, and
we may even con­verse with them as if they un­der­stand us and are able to
re­ply.  I be­lieve this is called an­thro­po­mor­phism: *“con­sid­er­ing
an­i­mals, ob­jects, etc., as hav­ing hu­man qual­i­ties”*.  I can al­so
un­der­stand how we be­come at­tached to our pets, al­low­ing them to live
in our homes and be­come, for all in­tents and pur­pos­es, mem­bers of our
fam­i­lies.

1. Would it be true to say that in nam­ing the male and fe­male do­mes­tic
   an­i­mals (those bred for food, trans­porta­tion, work etc.), many were
   per­son­i­fied by giv­ing them hu­man names?

In or­der to avoid pos­si­ble con­fu­sion; I am talk­ing about
clas­si­fi­ca­tion; for ex­am­ple, *hen* the fe­male chick­en,
*cock/roost­er* the male, and *chick* the young are dis­tinct words which
are not com­mon first names, where­as *tom*, *jake*, and *jen­ny* are.

As far as I am aware this does not hap­pen in the Ital­ian lan­guage. To
pro­vide a few ex­am­ples from Ital­ian:

- *pa­pe­ro e pa­pe­ra*  = drake/(fe­male) duck
- *asi­no e asi­na* = jack or jack­ass/(fe­male don­key) jen­ny
- *cav­al­lo e giu­men­ta* = horse/mare
- *gat­to e gat­ta* = tom­cat/(fe­male cat) queen
- *gal­lo e gal­li­na* = roost­er/hen
- *tacchi­no e tac­chi­no fem­mi­na* = (tur­key) tom/hen
- *can­guro, can­guro fem­mi­na e cuc­ci­o­lo di
  can­guro*[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/joey) = buck or jake/(fe­male kan­ga­roo)
  jill/(young) joey

I know not one in­stance where a do­mes­ti­cat­ed farm an­i­mal in Italy is
called by an Ital­ian *hu­man* name.

2. Is this phe­nomenon pe­cu­liar to English on­ly? Can any­one ex­plain
   its ori­gins? For ex­am­ple, why were the adult and young male tur­key both
   giv­en male hu­man names, and why is a young fe­male tur­key called a
   *jen­ny*?
3. Are there oth­er ex­am­ples in the an­i­mal king­dom where the young and
   adult an­i­mals have been giv­en “hu­man names”? I can think of on­ly two
   oth­ers but they are both adults: *Tom* an adult male cat and *drake* an
   adult male duck (I might be wrong, but I’m pret­ty sure I’ve heard *Drake*
   used as a per­son’s name).

<sub>*Edit*: I added the terms for male, fe­male, and young kan­ga­roos to the
orig­i­nal list.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, Drake is definitely a name. There was even a show with a Drake as the lead character.

Comment: [Buck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers): male deer, [Chick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_Hearn): baby chicken, Joey: baby kangaroo, [Goose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goose_Gossage), jenny: female donkey, jill: female ferret. Here's a webpage that has a bunch of [examples](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/animals/Animalbabies.shtml).

Comment: @tylerharms I've only heard of Buck (male rabbit?) as a name, thanks for reminding me :) The others are very unusual!

Comment: Also, in the case of ferrets, unlike turkeys, the male counterpart to a "jill" is a "hob".

Comment: Ooh there are lots. I didn't realize. Still someone might know the story behind Tom, jake and jenny. Thank you tylerharms :)

Comment: Possibly because a male duck is called 'a drake', in the same way that a male goose is a 'gander'. And a male cat is a 'tom'. It is interesting that English sometimes gives the male name to the species as a whole and sometimes the female. Ducks, geese, cats, sheep, cows, are all female and have male counterparts. But a 'dog' is male, its female being a 'bitch', also a fox, its lady a 'vixen'.

Comment: _Tom_ for a male cat comes from a children’s book called “The Life and Adventures of a Cat” (1760) featuring a cat named Tom. Perhaps _tom_ was used by analogy for some other male animals. In his comprehensive etym dict, Klein records: "jackass, n. male ass. — Compounded of jack, 'male of animals', and ass." Maybe _jake_ comes from _jack_ and was influenced by _drake_. I'm just guessing. _Jenny_ also might have something to do with _hen_. How's that for folk etymology? :-)

Comment: Dr. Drake Ramore.

Comment: The question seems to be why did an author choose to name a female turkey Jenny. That is a matter of opinion; you would have to ask the author.

Comment: @MετάEd, how do you figure that? As I read it, the question is why the English language has such a large number of male/female-specific animals that are seemingly derived from (or at least identical to) given names; nothing to do with any specific turkey or author.

Comment: @MετάEd Thank you Janus, I was about to ask if he was joking! I admit I found it a bit tricky to set up the question, I wanted to avoid exactly that possible confusion.

Comment: Is this about how certain animals are often given certain human first names *if they are given a first name at all*? Or is this about how animals *are move often given human first names* than in other languages in general? As to the first question, other languages certainly have human first names that are more common for certain animals. Dutch *Berta* is typical for cows, *Minoes* for female cats, *Henk* for a male horse, etc. But there may be fewer such connections than in English. Dutch does have a lot of first names that are exclusive to animals, like *Kwak*, *Vlekkie* ("Spot"), etc.

Comment: @Cerberus my question is about giving first names to animals, which we would normally think of as being human names. Why does English do that? Is it out of affection, is it for mnemonic purposes? Personally, I've only discovered now that a jenny is a female ass. Why am I reminded of Jennifer Lopez? Never mind, the turkey family I think is quite unique and now I'm curious to its origins. I will make one further edit to see if anyone will answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: If both of my interpretations are incorrect, and you simply mean giving first names to animals period, then the answer is that this is done in almost all cultures. It is done for obvious reasons: animals resemble humans in many ways, they invoke social emotions in us, and so we may anthropomorphise them, as we do even with many lifeless things, like boats and thunder and love. I still don't think that's what your question is about, though, because it is too detailed for that. What you do mean I don't know.

Comment: But human names are not given to all animals, think of horse, mare, foal, colt. And dog, bitch, pup. Pig, sow, and piglets. Why some animals and not others?

Comment: How about Jill, Boomer, and Joey?

Comment: @RyeBread Boomer is a male adult kangaroo *and* a name?! But yes, good suggestion. Do you know why they're called that?

Comment: "Jenny" is a knickname for Jennifer, "Joey" for Joseph, "Billy" for William, "Jack" for James.  So what's up with using only human knicknames for animal names?  Now I'm curious too, Mari-Lou!

Comment: Are you saying "giving first names" as in, "the name for this gender of that species is"? Because "giving a name" means "naming" which would be like giving your dog the name Fido.

Comment: @MrHen How am I phrase my question? Please see Janus Bahs Jacquet and Kristina Lopez's comments. I am not speaking about pet names, or the names a farmer might give to his chickens. He could call each and every single one as he pleases; Alberta, Rita, Tina etc. For example, why is a young kangaroo called "Joey" and not simply *young/baby kangaroo/cub/foal/roo*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: A more typical way to phrase this is, "Why are these animals *called* names that are also human names?"

Comment: Conversely, some Spanish surnames use terms for (or derived from) animals: *Garza* - stork/heron, *Oropez* - goldfish, *Lopez* - (derived from) wolf, *Gallo* - rooster, *Ochoa* - nickname for wolf, *Merlo* - blackbird, *Palomo* - dove, *Rana* - frog.

Comment: The French seem to occupy a position somewhere between the Italians and the English. Apparently only 35% of dogs in France have human names, and it varies according to region. The people in the west of France are apparently less likely to name their dogs after humans than those in the north and east.  I always knew the English were sentimental about animals but I had never realised before that not all nationalities name their domestic animals after humans. http://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/95/08/70/PDF/sociologie-prenoms-chiens.pdf

Comment: I actually took *Tom* as a vocative here, a “noun of direct address”, since in my own personal experience, in that position that is always its role. This can be fixed either by adding the missing comma or by not talking to people named *Tom*. :)

Comment: While *Drake* is certainly a name, I expect it wasn't a common *given* name until relatively recently. Even as a *surname*, it's not clear to me that naming humans *Drake* preceded calling male ducks *drakes*. (I have no citations for any of this, except that *Merriam-Webster* lists "14th century" for first known use of *drake* to mean male duck.)

Comment: This question is badly written. The title "Tom, Jake and Jenny aren't looking forward to Thanksgiving. Why?" gives no hint as to what the question actually is and is click-baity. 1a) "Is this phenomenon peculiar to English only?" Other languages are off-topic here. This question would be better on Linguistics. 1b) "Can anyone explain its origins?" The only on-topic question asked. 2) "Are there other examples in the animal kingdom where the young and adult animals have been given 'human names'?" Asking for lists of things is off topic.

Comment: The question makes it sound like this phenomenon exists in many animal categories. It does not. The turkey nomenclature is an exception. "Many were personified by giving them human names" is false. The turkey ones seem to be the only one you have come up with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some additional human given names that are in current general use for certain animals. I don't think that these have been explicitly identified by other answerers/commenters.

**Widespread General Use**

> **billy goat** [from *William*]
>
> **jackdaw**, **jackrabbit**, **jack mackerel**, **jack salmon**, **jacksmelt** (common name, both sexes) [from *John*]
>
> **jenny wren** [from *Janet*]
>
> **john mule, John Dory** (common name of the fish, for both sexes) [*John*]
>
> **magpie** [from *Margaret* plus *pie* in the sense of "pied {that is, blotched black-and-white} crow"]
>
> **molly mule** [from *Mary*]
>
> **nanny goat** [from *Anne*]
>
> **poll parrot** [from *Mary*, according to OED via [Word Origins](http://wordoriginsorg.yuku.com/topic/8116/PollParrot#.Uyc_6l4-P9U), but not gender-specific in use]
>
> **tomtit** (common name, both sexes) [from *Thomas*]

---

**Regional (and Possibly Obsolete) U.S. Use**

These names appear as entries in Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944) but are probably not in widespread use today:

> **Bessie cow** [from *Elizabeth*] ("A cow." The entry cites a 1942 article in the *Saturday Evening Post*.)
>
> **biddy** (for a hen or young chicken) [from *Bridget*, in its perhaps unrelated meaning of "hired girl" or "elderly woman"; "biddy" the chicken dates to 1601, and Merriam-Webster's says that the name is "perh[aps] imit[ative]," while "biddy" the working girl dates to circa 1861 and is "dim[inutive] of the name Bridget"]
>
> **bubbly-jock** [from *John*] (The entry says, "A turkey gobbler. 1930 central Pennsylvania mountains. Still or recently used. 1934 Chiefly Scottish. Webster's.")
>
> **jack** [from *John*] ("A male animal. 1923 northwestern Missouri Not used in mixed company. *Male*, n., is used. 1934 = male of certain animals. Webster's.")
>
> **jessie** [from *Jesse*] ("A 'critter.' 1942 Florida.")
>
> **Johnny, Johnnie** [from *John*] ("A male animal. 1934 Local U.S. Webster's.")
>
> **Old Ned** [from *Edward*] ("1904–1922 western North Carolina–eastern Tennessee 1936 southwest Missouri–northwest Arkansas 1941 1. Fat pork, bacon. 2. A boar.")

The strangest animal name entry in the *American Dialect Dictionary* is surely "Old Ned," which in some localities refers to certain delicious remains of the animal in question, though it may also refer to a whole (and presumably live) boar.

---

**False Alarms**

Two bird names that don't qualify because they are imitative of the bird's call, rather than being based on human given names:

> **bobwhite**
>
> **chuck-will's-widow**

Two designations that don't make the cut for other reasons:

> **pollywog** [probably comes not from the name *Polly* but from *poll* (in the sense of head) and *wiglen* (to wiggle)]
>
> **teddy bear** [doesn't apply generally to real bears]

And two involve the reverse case of names that arose from animal-specific words in other languages and later became common popular given names in English owing to the appeal of the animal:

> **mavis** [derived from Anglo-French *mauviz*, meaning "song thrush"]
>
> **robin** [derived from a root akin to the Danish dialect word *robijntje* and the Frisian word *robyntsje*, meaning "linnet"]

---

**A Note on Polite Avoidance of Certain Animal Names**

I was struck by the remark in the *American Dialect Dictionary* that, in the 1920s in northwestern Missouri, *jack* was not used to refer to a male animal "in mixed company." It turns out that, across much of the U.S. South and as far north as Nebraska, Kentucky and West Virginia, some rural folk considered various male animal identifications to be vulgar. None of the forbidden nouns would cause much of a stir today: "*Bull*, *boar*, *stallion* & *jack* are not used in mixed company, although *buck* (male sheep or goat) & *crower* (rooster) are." But squeamishness on this point led to such euphemisms as *male* ("Any male animal kept for breeding purposes"), *stock-male* (bull), *male-brute* (bull), *male-cow* (bull), *male-hog* (boar), and *male-pig* (boar), which were in use for at least the first four decades of the twentieth century in some parts of the United States. The only animal designations (by gender) I can think of that prompt similar recourse to polite circumlocutions today are *cock* and *bitch*.

Comment: My thanks to site participant Pete Kirkham for suggesting the relevance of _magpie_, _robin_, and _mavis_.

Answer (score 15):

The French word for “fox” is [*re­nard*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/renard), which comes from *Re­nart* (English
Rey­nard), the name of the fox in the me­di­ae­val fa­ble cy­cle that has come to be known as 
the [*Ro­man de Re­nart*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_de_Renart),
orig­i­nal­ly a Ger­man­ic per­son­al name (mod­ern Ger­man *Rein­hard*).
So this phe­nom­e­non is not unique to En­glish.

Comment: +1 for answering the question straight and to the point

Comment: This is a good answer but it has only *partially* answered my questions. Could you flesh this one out?

Answer (score 8):

Joey for a young kangaroo could be after [Joseph Banks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Banks), who apparently [first recorded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo#Terminology) the species in English.

Tom was a generic '[everyman' name](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Tom) from 14th c on, and if independence were associated as a quality, it would link well to tomcat.

Jack is a traditional [story character](http://ccb.lis.illinois.edu/Projects/storytelling/jsthomps/tales.htm) who exhibits foolish behaviour, which would link to jackass.

On the flip side, Reynard the fox as a proper name [evolved](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Reynard?s=t) etymologically from 'hard to reckon or reason with'.

It would seem that there's a linking pattern with either a person or a quality.

As to why these are part of the English lexicon and not the Italian, I have no idea. What about French, German, Spanish?

While irrelevant in terms of answering the specific question, there's an interesting list of the etymological origin of animal names [here](http://iberianature.com/britainnature/miscellaneous/etymology-of-mammal-names-in-english/).

FURTHER ADDITION

In French, [Baudet](https://archive.org/stream/etymologicaldict00bracrich#page/46/mode/2up) is the equivalent of Jackass - the etymology associates this with a human quality of being constantly in a good mood, and that crosses over to a surname. Presumably the link is related to the 'hee-haw' being interpreted as a laugh.

And if you look at the entry [here](https://archive.org/stream/etymologicaldict00bracrich#page/202/mode/2up) for Jacasser, you'll find that it says 'Proper names of men are often applied to birds'... eg Pierrot: sparrow.

I don't have time to do the same for other languages - the methodology is easy. Use some of the terms on the page given in tylerharms' [link](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/animals/Animalbabies.shtml) in the comment above, punch them into Google translate, find an on-line etymological dictionary and rely on a bit of common sense and luck to lead you to some answers.

The gradual anthropomorphisation of animals is something that interests me - it's clearly traceable visually in the history of illustrations to Aesop's Fables - a sample which spans 2,200 years of the Fox and Stork can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFEKaShjJp4). The transformation sees them go from wild (human and animal worlds very separate) to wild animals juxtaposed on the human world, to 'tamer' animals assimilated to the human world (clothed, civilised). As we hit the so-called 'age of enlightenment', interestingly, the human and animal get closer, while the depiction of the animals becomes more naturalistic, separating them superficially, yet paving the way to bringing them nearer in behaviour and treatment later. The names, as far as I'm aware always stay very fixedly in the animal kingdom. There's a history of the use of fables in cultures of repression. It may be that there's a related link between animal and human names. Happy for someone to prove this right or wrong. It's just a hypothesis at the moment.

Comment: I was wondering if this was a peculiarity of the English language  phenomenon, I'd be delighted to hear if other languages give *human names* to domesticated animals. By the way, who was Joseph Banks?

Comment: I don't think it's quite correct to regard animals as being given human names. I'm not disputing the examples given but they are either very generic names (Jack, Tom), or they have gone the other way: from animals to humans. For example, Buck is a relatively common nickname or friendly term in North America in the sense of 'young buck' expressing youthful virility and the name Reynard from fox emphasises the fox's cunning. In the North of England men and women can be familiarly addressed as 'cock' and 'hen' although this usage is old-fashioned.

Comment: I hate to break the Joey bubble because I did comment on it a while back but I did distinctly remember seeing something (National Geographic/History/Discovery?) that told that the name derives from a Aboriginal word that sounds like Joey.   I have no idea what said word is but when I heard it, it sounded like Joey.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I know of the 'kangaroo' bubble being burst - it does mean grey or black marsupial of this type in the indigenous language, not 'I don't understand'. I wasn't aware of there being a link in the language to Joey - and I checked this paper: http://anthroweb.ucsd.edu/~jhaviland/Publications/HavilandOceania.pdf. If you can find a precise link, I'd be glad to know what other theories of the origin of Joey there might be out there.

Comment: @LeonConrad - Just a quick google and you will see articles referring to an Aboriginal name for Joey, but nothing I found in a couple of minutes that substantiates it with anything solid.

Comment: Apparently according to this [source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/joey) a *joey* is a name for many young animals and for a child. It could derive from the Australian word, *joè*, or be the contracted form of Joseph, which has many meanings in Australian slang.

Answer (score 4):

### Tom

The OED has this for *tom*:

> The male of various beasts and birds; perh. first for a male cat: see tom cat n.; cf. also Compounds 2a.
>
> 1791   G. Huddesford *Salmagundi* (1793) 141   Cats..Of titles obsolete, or yet in use, Tom, Tybert, Roger, Rutterkin, or Puss.
>
> ...
>
> Compounds 2a. In names of animals, denoting the male; see also tom cat n.
>
> 1772   T. Bridges *Burlesque Transl. Homer* (rev. ed.) v. 192   And, like Tom puss, o'er pantiles dance.

In all, it's applied to: tom puss, tom-dog, tom-turkey, tom-parrot, tom-bird, tom-chicken, tom-pheasant, tom-swan, tom-rats, tom-rabbits, tom-mice, tom-hedgehogs [etc.].

For the etymology of tom-cat:

> In 1760 was published an anonymous work ‘The Life and Adventures of a Cat’, which became very popular. The hero, a male or ‘ram’ cat, bore the name of Tom, and is commonly mentioned as ‘Tom the Cat’, as ‘Tybert the Catte’ is in Caxton's Reynard the Fox. Thus Tom became a favourite allusive name for a male cat (see quot. 1791 at Tom n.1 6); and people said ‘this cat is a Tom’ or a ‘Tom cat’.

### Jenny

For *jenny*:

> Used as a prefix to denote a female animal, as jenny-ass, and esp. in names of birds, as jenny-hooper, jenny-howlet, and sometimes loosely applied without reference to sex.

First quotation:

> 1600   R. Surflet tr. C. Estienne & J. Liébault *Maison Rustique* i. xxii. 122   To preuent the danger of owles and iennie whuppers.

The etymology of the general sense:

> A female personal name, pet-form or familiar equivalent of Janet (or, by confusion with Jinny or Jeanie, of Jane), and so serving as a feminine of Jack. Hence, like Jack, used as a feminine prefix, and as the name of machines.

Comment: I don't know what a hooper or a howlett is (Am?) but there's little Jenny Wrren in the nursery rhyme [Sing a Song of Sixpence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sing_a_Song_of_Sixpence)

Answer (score 4):

*João* and *Maria* (John and Mary in English) are very com­mon names in Bra­zil­ian
Por­tu­guese, but not on­ly in hu­mans. There are some birds that take these
names.

Here are only a few of many:

- *João-de-Ba­rro* (Clay John) = Red Ov­en­bird
- *João-Po­bre* (Poor John) = Sooty Ty­ran­nulet
- *João-Bo­bo* (Sil­ly/Gul­lible John) = White-eared Puff­bird
- *Ma­ria-Le­que* (Mary Fold­ing Fan) = Crowned Roy­al Fly­catch­er
- *Ma­ria-Pre­ta* (Black Mary) = Crest­ed Black Ty­rant
- *Ma­ria-Bo­ni­ta* (Pret­ty Mary) = Black-chest­ed Ty­rant

Answer (score 3):

**Gilbert or Gib-cat**

Yet another male cat variant. It's used by Shakespeare in *1 Henry IV* to indicate a castrated cat, and stems from the name Gilbert.

[More info 1](http://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/brewers/gib-cat.html)

[More Info 2](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Grose-VulgarTongue/g/gib-cat.html)

[More Info 3](http://books.google.ie/books?id=BvdBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=gilbert%20gib%20cat&source=bl&ots=RYuFhQAh_n&sig=rZUidFRl97gm7fURAJOeCdmVphM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1ZohU8P_Haug7Abc-oGYAQ&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=gilbert%20gib%20cat&f=false)