# English terms for a female wolf and a female owl?

Tags: nouns, gender-positive

In the English language, what are the right terms for a female wolf and a female owl; perhaps "she wolf"  and "owl hen"?

Are there distinct or separate words in English used for feminine?  I checked in Wikipedia +other websites but found only "she-wolf" and "owl-hen".

Comment: The word for a female dog is bitch.  My guess is that this would be the word for a female wolf, except for a reluctance to use the word bitch.

Comment: It's not exactly an everyday collocation, but a female owl would normally be called be [*a hen owl*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+hen+owl%22), not *an owl hen*.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't Tom, Jake and Jenny looking forward to Thanksgiving?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133237/why-arent-tom-jake-and-jenny-looking-forward-to-thanksgiving)

Comment: that means hen-owl and she-wolf are correct and no other specific name is used

Comment: No need for hyphens in "hen-owl" and "she-wolf".

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries says: "bitch NOUN 1A female dog, wolf, fox, or otter."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+wolf%2Cshe-wolf%2C+bitch+wolf&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20wolf%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20-%20wolf%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbitch%20wolf%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ngrams are useful, but not the law.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - well, they give an indication of usage as per the evidence provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You used to have ***[wolfess](https://books.google.it/books?id=j5vWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=wolfess%20meaning&source=bl&ots=aNAvk_5_4I&sig=-OYkRaRnzX4UAiVJcFTMjMGZCsM&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIm42tuczeAhVGXhoKHcqkADUQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=wolfess%20meaning&f=false)***, now an archaic term. [She-wolf](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/she-wolf) or *female wolf* are the terms commonly used:

> Wolfess, the medieval term for a she-wolf, is now rarely used in Present Day English except to mean a woman that is sexually aggressive.

(Studies in Linguistic Variation and Change: From Old to Middle English)

***[Female owl](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=female%20owl%2C%20hen%20owl&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfemale%20owl%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chen%20owl%3B%2Cc0)*** is the more common term as far as owl is concerned; “hen owl” appears to be a more informal expression.

Comment: Incidentally, tigress is still in use.

Comment: @Joshua Isn't tigress mostly used metaphorically?

Comment: @gerrit: Yeah, quite a lot. But it's also used literally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the words you are looking for (as seen with the answer bitch for a female dog) is that those words are normally assigned to husbanded animals.

Hen / rooster, cow / bull, mare / stallion, etc.

Edit: Adding a generic 'ess' is the equivalent of saying 'female of' and in this case your best options seem to be 'she wolf' or 'wolfess' and 'hen owl'